# MySQL replication error 2003

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to establish replication between two linux boxes.

My master and slave are on LAN, both can ping each other and can telnet ip 3306, meaning the mysql ports are open on both ends.

I created a replication user on master and on slave:

```
change master to master_host ='master_ip';
change master to master_user ='replicator';
change master to master_password ='password';
```

Master gives this when showing master status:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |   546050 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I'm getting the following error on show slave status:

```
Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
..
Last_IO_Errno: 2003
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replicator@master_ip:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
```

Anyone has any ideas as to what this could be, or any other info you may need?

EDIT:

On the slave the last line of show slave status\G reads:

Master_Server_Id: 0

Shouldn't that say 1 as that is master's ID?

Comment: Check permissions! Try to log in to mysql server using replication credentials! Also check SELINUX.

Comment: When I try to login from slave to master with the credentials I get the same error 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Search for "grant" and you'll find:

```
# Grant access rights:
GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, FILE, SUPER, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, RELOAD ON *.* TO replicant@'%';
Flush Privileges;
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll find out! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to flush privileges after GRANT statement. From MySQL documentation.

If you modify the grant tables directly using statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, your changes have no effect on privilege checking until you either restart the server or tell it to reload the tables. If you change the grant tables directly but forget to reload them, your changes have no effect until you restart the server. This may leave you wondering why your changes seem to make no difference!

To tell the server to reload the grant tables, perform a flush-privileges operation. This can be done by issuing a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement or by executing a mysqladmin flush-privileges or mysqladmin reload command.

If you modify the grant tables indirectly using account-management statements such as GRANT, REVOKE, SET PASSWORD, or RENAME USER, the server notices these changes and loads the grant tables into memory again immediately.