# error during master(local host) to master(aws) replication of mysql server

Tags: mysql, replication

mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.12
                  Master_User: chan
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 478
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 478
              Relay_Log_Space: 107
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'chan@192.168.1.12:3306' - retry-time: 10  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified

Comment: I am doing replication from my local mysql server to aws mysql server.I am getting the error posted.Can anyone please help me on this error?

Comment: I had the same error until today, but granting more permissions to the replication user (on master) solved it. See [MySQL replication error 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412090/mysql-replication-error-2003)